# Unable to connect to friend's LAN server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting, networking

I am unable to connect to my friend's LAN server, on the Technic launcher mod pack, "Vivacity".

When he puts it up, I can't even see it in my server menu. This has also been an issue when trying to use LAN servers for other games, such as Garry's Mod. When I enter the port number and try to direct connect, it says
***"java.net.SocketException:Network is unreachable:no further information"***.

I tried using our public IP as the port, in an attempt to add it to my server list, but it says ***"java.net.SocketException: Connection refused: no further information"***

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does using your public IP as the port mean? A port is completely different than an IP

Comment: Try portforwarding,

Comment: But I think AP Coding is on the right track, since you don't seem to understand the difference between IP and port you're probably putting in the wrong address

Answer (score 2):

I had this error before when trying to play with my friend. Try this method:

---

Assuming that you have a computer running Windows:

1: Press **Windows Key** + **R** to open the run dialogue

2: Type in "cmd" to open up the command prompt

3: In the cmd, type "ipconfig"

4: This should bring up a list of addresses. The address you want is the **IPv4** address

5: Lastly, open up Minecraft and try connecting using your **IPv4** address

---

If you are running on a Mac:

1: Click on the **Apple Logo** at the top left corner

2: Go to **System Preferences**

3: Under **System Preferences**, click on **Network**

4: At the right, it should say the status, and under that, an address in the format of **192.168.X.XXX**

5: Open up Minecraft and try connecting using that address

Sorry for the information overhaul, but this did work for me.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. Did you friend publish the world to LAN? He can do that via the `/publish` command
2. Don't connect through the server list. Just go into your Multiplayer tab and scroll down. You should see his world there.
3. Do you have different mods? Make sure your mods that you have currently installed are the **exact** same.
4. Make sure that you are playing on the same version.

Point 1 and 2 are the most important. Also, as a side note, don't use an IP as a port. They are completely different.